# My first package stopped to work!

Tags: pstricks, package-writing

some years ago I wrote the simple package PSBao.sty. I stopped using it two years ago and now it doesn't work any more. I'm not able to find the cause. Can someone help me?
Unfortunately it was my first and last attempt to write a package so it is a little spaghetti-like and I can't add a MWE. Sorry!

ADD: I forgot to say that I use TexStudio with MikTex and run it with PDFLaTex. Sorry again!

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{psbao}
\begin{document}
\centering
\setbaounit{.4cm}
\initbao[0,%
4,3,5,1,1,1,5,0,%
4,4,1,2,0,0,0,0,%
0,0,0,3,5,8,4,1,%
2,2,1,1,1,2,3,0,%
0]
\begin{showbaoboard}
\end{showbaoboard}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to @user187802 for the MWE!

**Adding** the package **auto-pst-pdf**, the **postscript** eviroment as suggested by @user187802 to the MWE and the command
**pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex**
I get a correct **mwe-autopp.pdf** no **mwe.pdf** and the following warnings:

```
runsystem(echo " ")...executed.

runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.

runsystem(echo "auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation")...executed.

runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.

runsystem(del "mwe-autopp.log")...executed.

runsystem(del "mwe-autopp.dvi")...executed.

runsystem(del "mwe-autopp.ps")...executed.

runsystem(del "mwe-autopp.pdf")...executed.

runsystem(latex -disable-write18 -jobname="mwe-autopp" -interaction=batchmode  
"\let \APPmakepictures \empty \input  mwe.tex")...executed.

runsystem(dvips -Ppdf -o "mwe-autopp.ps" "mwe-autopp.dvi")...executed.

runsystem(ps2pdf  "mwe-autopp.ps" "mwe-autopp.pdf")...executed.

runsystem(pdfcrop  "mwe-autopp.pdf" "mwe-pics.pdf")...executed.


Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Creation of mwe-pics.pdf failed.
This warning occured on input line 128.


Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Could not create mwe-pics.pdf. Auxiliary files not deleted.
This warning occured on input line 128.

runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.

runsystem(echo "auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation")...executed.

runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.

Package pst-pdf Warning: File `mwe-pics.pdf' not found.
```

Comment: you need to clarify your question, you can't simply post 700 lines of code without saying what you expected it to do, or what error you get

Comment: I get no error from latex

Comment: You say this is a `.sty` package, but it has `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.  Those shouldn't be in a package.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:tikz-pgf] or [tag:texstudio]?

Comment: The package ([psbao on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/psbao)) seems to work fine with lualatex and xelatex

Comment: I do however get an error when trying to compile with `auto-pst-pdf` and shell escape

Comment: @David Carlsle you had time to count the lines of code but you did read the message! Sorry,

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel all humans make mistakes! ;)

Comment: I didn't count them, (my editor reported it)  I took the time to copy your example,run it , check that there was no error. As I got no error and you gave no information at all in your question about what error you got I left a comment suggesting you clarify the question.  What part of your question do you think I did not read?

Comment: @mbert: you need the `postscript` environment

Answer (score 3):

Run it with `lualatex` and your package will work:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{psbao}
\begin{document}
\centering
\setbaounit{.4cm}
\initbao[0,%
4,3,5,1,1,1,5,0,%
4,4,1,2,0,0,0,0,%
0,0,0,3,5,8,4,1,%
2,2,1,1,1,2,3,0,%
0]
\begin{showbaoboard}
\end{showbaoboard}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It also works with `latex->drips->pspdf`  and also for `pdflatex` and package `auto-pst-pdf` and the `postscript` environment. The following works with `pdflatex --shell-escape ...`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[pspdf=-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY]{auto-pst-pdf} 
\usepackage{psbao}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{postscript}
\setbaounit{.4cm}
\initbao[0,%
4,3,5,1,1,1,5,0,%
4,4,1,2,0,0,0,0,%
0,0,0,3,5,8,4,1,%
2,2,1,1,1,2,3,0,%
0]
\begin{showbaoboard}
\end{showbaoboard}
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it does work with luaLatex but not with pdflatex and auto-pst-pdf!

Comment: I showed you how it works with `pdflatex`. and `auto-pst-pdf`! You need the `postscript` environment.

Comment: yes, you showed how to do and I did run your modified MWE but it doesn't work. I'll try again.

Comment: "it doesn't work"  is _not_. a useful description of your problem ...  In your new MWE the `postscript` environment is missing

Comment: @nino_user183677 If it does not work, you need to tell about the error you get. Otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Comment: @user187802 I copied your MWE, but when I used it i did use pdflatex, auto-pst-pdf and postscript environment! Please look at what I added to my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JasperHabicht you are right but I'm getting mad because I use my .sty package every two or three years with the same .tex file with only some text corrections, but every time it gives errors which I don't succeed to correct after a long googling! So when I ask help here I'm not "clearheaded"!

Comment: Ghostscript changes last year its behaviour, the reason why you need `\usepackage[pspdf=-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY]{auto-pst-pdf}` . I have this option already in my Ghostscript config.